# PHP - How can I remove image in Froala text editor v4?

Tags: php, text-editor, unlink, froala

I am trying to remove image in froala text editor, I can upload image, but i can't delete image.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@latest/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="sample">
<h2>File upload example.</h2>
<form>
<textarea id="edit" name="content"></textarea>
</form>
</div>

<script>
    
 new FroalaEditor('#edit', {
    
    imageUploadURL: 'upload_image.php',
    
    fileUploadParams: {
    id: 'my_editor'
    }
    })

    var editor = new FroalaEditor('#edit');

editor.opts.events['image.removed'] = function (e, editor, $img) {
  $.ajax({
    // Request method.
    method: 'POST',

    // Request URL.
    url: 'delete_image.php',

    // Request params.
    data: {
      src: $img.attr('src')
    }
  })
  .done (function (data) {
    console.log ('Image was deleted');
  })
  .fail (function (err) {
    console.log ('Image delete problem: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
  })
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

upload_image.php :

```
<?php
  
  try {
  // File Route.
  $fileRoute = "/uploads/";
  
  $fieldname = "file";
  
  // Get filename.
  $filename = explode(".", $_FILES[$fieldname]["name"]);
  
  // Validate uploaded files.
  // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  
  // Get temp file name.
  $tmpName = $_FILES[$fieldname]["tmp_name"];
  
  // Get mime type.
  $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $tmpName);
  
  // Get extension. You must include fileinfo PHP extension.
  $extension = end($filename);
  
  // Allowed extensions.
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "svg", "blob");
  
  // Allowed mime types.
  $allowedMimeTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/x-png", "image/png", "image/svg+xml");
  
  // Validate image.
  if (!in_array(strtolower($mimeType), $allowedMimeTypes) || !in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
  throw new \Exception("File does not meet the validation.");
  }
  
  // Generate new random name.
  $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;
  $fullNamePath = dirname(__FILE__) . $fileRoute . $name;

  // Check server protocol and load resources accordingly.
  if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "off") {
  $protocol = "https://";
  } else {
  $protocol = "http://";
  }
  
  // Save file in the uploads folder.
  move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fullNamePath);
  
  // Generate response.
  $response = new \StdClass;
  $response->link = $protocol.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).$fileRoute . $name;
  
  // Send response.
  echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
  
  } catch (Exception $e) {
  // Send error response.
  echo $e->getMessage();
  http_response_code(404);
  }
  ?>
```

delete_image.php :

```
<?php
 try {
  $response = FroalaEditor_Image::delete($_POST['src']);
  echo stripslashes(json_encode('Success'));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  http_response_code(404);
}
?>
```

I didn't find any other tutorial in this field and the official site tutorial was not enough.
I tried for a whole day, but it didn't work.
I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you looked at their docs? https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/v1.2/docs/server-integrations/php-delete-image/ What you have looks very different...

Comment: This page also looks like it has more information: https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/v1.2/docs/concepts/delete-image/

Comment: thanks, i saw this, this is for v1.2 , my version is 4

Comment: In that case, do you see where the issue occurs? Any errors in the JavaScript console? Do you devtools show that the network request happens successfully? Any PHP errors?

Comment: in devtools/network i got this : Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
index5.php:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'image.removed')
    at index5.php:31:37